# while and for loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

How can I add up 3 inputs from the scanner using one variable, and while & for loop only (no array)?[CLICK THIS LINK TO SEE IMAGE INCLUDING INSTRUCTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DekCP.jpg)

HERE IS THE CODE THE NEEDE TO COMPLETE THE TASK IN THE IMAGE.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ass1b
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
    String taxPayerName;
    int totalInc;
    double totalTax;
    Scanner inText = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the name of the tax payer==> ");
    taxPayerName = inText.nextLine();


    Scanner inNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the income for "+ taxPayerName +" ==> " );
    totalInc = inNumber.nextInt();
    if (totalInc < 18200)
    {
        totalTax = 0;
        System.out.print("The tax that " + taxPayerName + " has to pay is $"+ totalTax);
    }
    else if(totalInc < 37000)
    {
        totalTax=((totalInc - 18200)* 0.19);
        System.out.print("The tax that " + taxPayerName + " has to pay is $"+ totalTax);
    }
    else if(totalInc < 87000)
    {
        totalTax=(3572 +(totalInc - 37000)* 0.325);
        System.out.print("The tax that " + taxPayerName + " has to pay is $"+ totalTax);
    }
    else if(totalInc < 180000)
    {
        totalTax=(19822 +(totalInc - 87000)* 0.37);
        System.out.print("The tax that " + taxPayerName + " has to pay is $"+ totalTax);
    }
    else
    {
        totalTax = (54232 + (totalInc - 180000)*0.47);
        System.out.print("The tax that " + taxPayerName + " has to pay is $"+ totalTax);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the main questions seems to be: *How can I add up 3 inputs from the scanner?*

One scanner can be used multiple times, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println("value : " + scanner.nextInt());
    }
}
```

This code would a for loop and one scanner object to ask the user five times for a integer. With this you should be able to complete the exercise. Now you just need to have an additional variable which keeps track of the total tax and then finally calculate the average tax.

In the future try to ask a more specific question, instead of just asking for the answer, because it seems this is a homework assignment. So I tried to help you out with general code, which doesn't answer the question directly.